# Get-ADUser Filter AccountExpirationDate

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm observing a discrepancy between how Active Directory date objects are set vs how they are retrieved and searched with -Filter.  Observe:

First I set an expiration date:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> set-aduser testaccount -AccountExpirationDate '12/25/2024 00:05:00' -Credential $CRED 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser testaccount -Properties AccountExpirationDate 


AccountExpirationDate : 12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM
DistinguishedName     : CN=Test Account,OU=Test,OU=CU Users,DC=ad,DC=contosso,DC=com
Enabled               : True
GivenName             : Systems
Name                  : Test Account
ObjectClass           : user
ObjectGUID            : {snip}
SamAccountName        : testaccount
SID                   : {snip}
Surname               : Test1c
UserPrincipalName     : testaccount@contosso.com
```

Then I try to search for all users with that Expiration Date, a couple of ways:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq "12/25/2024 00:05:00"' -Credential $CRED

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq "12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM"' -Credential $CRED

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $T=(get-date '12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM')

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq $T' -Credential $CRED

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Nada.  I figure I'm missing something between how AD stores that date value and how it's retrieved and displayed.

Comment: You need a datetime : Get-ADUser -Filter "AccountExpirationDate -eq [DateTime].Parse('12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM')"  -Credential $CRED

Comment: @jdweng no, thats wrong.

Comment: @jdweng that's almost right:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $T=[DateTime]"12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq $T'

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: You time is getting milliseconds so date isn't working.  You can truncate to seconds with following : [DateTime]::FromBinary([Timespan]::TicksPerSecond * ($date.Ticks / [Timespan]::TicksPerSecond))

Answer (score 1):

`AccountExpirationDate` is a friendly attribute given by the AD Module and it represents the translation from file time of [`AccountExpires`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-accountexpires). Looking at your snippets, one of them should work properly:

```bash
Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq $T'
```

The above is only failing because the date you're seeing in `AccountExpirationDate` has been converted to your local time, if you want to query back for a user having that exact date set you would need to convert that date [`ToUniversalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.touniversaltime?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-touniversaltime) beforehand:

```bash
$T = (Get-Date '12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM').ToUniversalTime()
Get-ADUser -Filter 'AccountExpirationDate -eq $T' -Credential $CRED
```

In this case, while using a [*literal string `'`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3), the `datetime` instance (`$T`) is passed as-is to the AD Filter provider which then converts this date [`.ToFileTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletime?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tofiletime).

The other examples will never work because the AD Filter is receiving a date in the format of `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` and it has no clue how to deal with that.

If you wanted to use a *expandable string `"`* for your filter you would need to do the following:

```bash
$date = (Get-Date '12/25/2024 12:05:00 AM').ToUniversalTime().ToFileTime()
# this:
Get-ADUser -Filter "accountExpires -eq '$date'"
# or this:
Get-ADUser -Filter "accountExpirationDate -eq '$date'"
```

Comment: @mklement0 ahh I see, you mean if `"accountExpires -eq $date"` works. Yeah it does work :) (as long as `$date` is a file time already)

Comment: In all cases in these examples, the provider converts the filters to their LDAP representation `(accountExpires=133795875000000000)`.